# moving running process to another computer

Tags: memory-management, process, linux-kernel, task

Is that possible to move a running application from a computer to another one that have an identical configuration?

My problem is the following : I have a process on my computer that is running since 4 days and I want to restart the computer without loosing the 4 days work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Checkpoint/Restore In Userspace (CRIU, https://criu.org) to snapshot a running process and restore it on an other host.

Have a look at Live migration of a process in [How can process snapshot/restore help save your day?](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/how-can-process-snapshotrestore-help-save-your-day)

Comment: It seems to be what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can solve this problem. I will tell 2 methods
1) Through profiling and final push through communication
2) Through regular updates over network communication

**1) Through profiling**

In this method, process on Host H1 will keep writing the status to its local database and when its time to take over, it will push the required data to H2 where the other process can do warm start

**2) Through regular network communication**

In this method process on H1 sends data/payload through TCP/UDP whichever you prefer and finally can send one notification to do a warm takeover by H2